# How can insignificant beings (microscopic organisms, insects, plants, etc.) ever acquire enough merit to be born as humans?

Tags: philosophy, life

And without earning a human birth, one cannot attain liberation.

Comment: They do. Their micro karmas are not very obvious to us. No two goats are same. No two trees bear same fruits or flowers. It is the Aatman inside them which differentiates their quality of karma. Not all cows will fight their butcher or for their calves, but those who do perform kshatriya karma. No?

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate question. ALL living organisms have a jiva. The individual cells in your body all have their own individual jivas, as well as the the totality of what you identify as 'you'. All jivas evolve and attain liberation.

Comment: Can you give a source for human birth (or at least human birth, otherwise that would be obviously wrong) being required for liberation?

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa is it not obvious? Note: we are not including the elephant Gajendra because normal elephants can neither speak nor plead for Vishnu's help, in distress. Only humans can make a conscious attempt at attaining God and Moksha. Microscopic organisms or insects or plants cannot do that.

Comment: @Anthro They can still do the processes by accident like meditating on their existence or God's. Just by living and making decisions they can blindly, slowly go towards liberation.